# Can we use ::-webkit-scrollbar in React Native?

Tags: react-native, emotion

Can I use ::-webkit-scrollbar and ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb in React Native while styling  ??

I want to do something like this , using '@emotion/native' or '@emotion/primitive'

```
import styled, { css } from '@emotion/native'

<View style={css`
        div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
            background-color: red;
          }
        `} >
```